# Equivalent To "Exit Sub and Exit For " in VBA in google apps script for google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have tried searching for "Exit Sub " equivalent in Google apps script and I am not finding from the resources I know. Can i get the equivalent which is much needed in my project. THANK YOU IN ADVANCE..

Comment: google apps script is javascript. look at a basic javascript introduction.

Comment: I agree with above comment. for example the for loop : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this question was never answered? I had the same question, and here's the answer I came up with:

Using the `break` statement substitutes for `Exit For`, as in this simple example. For `Exit Sub` consider using the `return` statement.

```
function exitFor(){
  var limit = 2;  // or change to 7 to see the For loop completed
  for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){
    Logger.log("i="+i);
    if(i>=limit){
      // code
      break;
    };
  }
  if(i>=limit){
    Logger.log("exited For loop early");
  }else{
    Logger.log("completed For loop");
  };
}
```

Here are the log outputs for when `limit`=2 and `limit`=7:

```
When limit = 2:
 i=0
 i=1
 i=2
 exited For loop early

When limit = 7:
 i=0
 i=1
 i=2
 i=3
 i=4
 i=5
 completed For loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple conversion of a function that prints a message to the screen:

```
'Vba
Sub printMsg(msg as String)
  MsgBox msg
Exit Sub

//GAS
function printMsg(msg)
{
  Browser.msgBox(msg);
}
```

These are both equivalent functions/methods.